# How can I write sha256 hash to Ethereum blockchain usin Go language

Tags: blockchain, contract-deployment

I need to write plain text to Ethereum blockchain. How can I do that using smart contracts and get contract address?

Answer (score 1):

Solidity does provide the function [`sha256()`](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html#mathematical-and-cryptographic-functions). And go does provide package [`sha256`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/sha256/). Since SHA2 is a standard both should be interoperable.

Comment: I mean I want to write just plain text. It doesn't matter sha256 or not, it could be "Hello World". Can I put plain text instead of bytecode to a smart contract?

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand what you are asking. Do you want to write a contract that stores plaint text messages?

Answer (score 0):

Write a solidity contract that returns your string value. Something like this:

`function returnValue() constant returns (string){
      return "Hello World"; 
 }`